# Is it possible to open a Lightning Tab with Workspace API without URL Parameters

Tags: lightning, console, workspaceapi

I am making a call using the [workspaceAPI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:workspaceAPI/documentation) to open a new tab in a Lightning Workspace. I am passing a number of variables via the `state` parameter, which appear in the URL as parameters after the tab is opened.

Is it possible to pass variables into the state ***without*** having them appended to the URL as parameters?

I ask because some of these parameters contain sensitive information that should not be transmitted as part of a URL request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and I've managed this with standard `window.btoa(str)` and `window.atob(str)` functions.

Before you set into the state, you can encrypt the variable values(String, number, object all did work for me) as below.

```
var original = 'Madhura';
var encValue = window.btoa(original);
console.log(encValue);     // prints : TWFkaHVyYQ==

workspaceAPI.openSubtab({
    parentTabId: enclosingTabId,
    pageReference: {
        "type": "standard__component",
        "attributes": {
            "componentName": "c__greetings"
        },
        "state": {
            "uid": "1",
            "c__name": encValue
        }
    }
});
```

So in the `greetings` component you can get the encrypted value in the usual way and then decrypt it into the original value as,

```
var myPageRef = cmp.get("v.pageReference");
var encryptedName = myPageRef.state.c__name;
var original = window.atob(encryptedName);
console.log(original);     // prints : Madhura
```